# Minimum cost in consulting company problem

Tags: optimization, operations-research

I would like to know how could I solve this following problem, I am trying to find a solution but don't know what to begin with:

> A consulting company estimates its business for the next five months, in hours, at 6000, 7000, 8000, 9500, 11000  hours,  respectively. Currently the company employs 50 consultants, each at 160  hours/month, paid 2000  euros/month. To meet demand, company must recruit and retain new consultants. Training takes one month and 50 hours of supervision from an existing consultant. Trainees are paid 1000 euros/month. After training, 5% of the trainees leave the firm.
>
> Plan the activity to meet the demand and incur the minimum cost.

Comment: What is the question? The problem you have quoted doesn't ask anything. Please also add any work you have already done, as more people are likely to attempt to answer your question this way, as it stands it looks like a 'do my homework for me' type question which is frowned upon here

Comment: edited the main post

Comment: To construct a mathematical programming formulation, start with defining the decision variables.

Comment: At 12 1/2 euros/hour for their consultants, it's no wonder that none of them are good enough to effectively plan the company's activity.